# XapCacheFile.xml not generated when deploying WP8 cocos2dx project in device

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I am getting the following error when trying to deploy WP8 cocos2dx project on device.

```
Could not find file 'E:\Projects\cocos2d-x-2.2.1\projects\MyProject\proj.wp8\ARM\Debug\XapCacheFile.xml'. Please rebuild the solution and try again.Deployment of application to device failed.
```

I can see **XapCacheFile.xml** was generated in **proj.wp8\Debug** folder, but this seems to generated when deploying for emulator.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Clean and Rebuild the solution.
It would fix the problem